# Do I need activerecord in my sinatra application?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra

So I have a sinatra application that displays my database information. It does not take user input and does not POST, it only GET's and displays the info.

Now a friend suggested me to use `ActiveRecord`, and from what I can tell it is mostly used for developing the database and routes. But since I have that done is there any advantage to using `ActiveRecord` in my program or I am good without it?

Comment: If it works don't touch it... The Rule

Comment: "If it ain't broke, don't fix it."

Comment: It sounds like a lightweight web app. If so, try not to use heavyloaded libraries such as ActiveRecord

Comment: There is no advantage to using `ActiveRecord` if your app does not interact with a database. In that case, `ActiveRecord` is pretty useless, actually. Why did your friend suggest `AR`? Are you planning on using a database back-end at some point? In that case, yes, `ActiveRecord` could be very useful so you don't have to write SQL queries by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more based on personal preferences.

You could read some articles about **ActiveRecord vs DataMapper** and decide what to use.

For example [this one](http://jgaskins.org/blog/2012/04/20/data-mapper-vs-active-record/).